# Wes Bos drum machine - remove transition is not working

Tags: javascript, function, repo

I coded along with Wes Bos drum machine tutorial but my code is not working right.
The following function is not executed:

```
function removeTransition(e) {
    if (e.propertyName !== 'transform') return;
    this.classList.remove('playing');
  }
```

I can't figure out why. I think the error has to be somewhere in the html but I just can not find it.
You can find the whole code on this repo https://github.com/BorisKarl/drum-machine.
Any help is appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine for me: https://rawcdn.githack.com/BorisKarl/drum-machine/7602f2f22639c5e8c023778f7c05b371da39ac51/drmch.html

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman It isn’t. None of the `playing` classes are removed when the CSS transition ends.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Ahhh okay! Got it. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for posting the link! I totally forgot about this important fact, I used "defer" to solve this. Should I delete the question now? Sorry for asking, still new here.